# Constructor Function vs Factory Function in regards of creating a getter

Tags: javascript

I have tried to create getters using both approaches 
- factory function

```
function CreateCircle(radius) {
  return {
    radius,
    get area() {
        return this.radius * 20;
    }
   }
}
```

- and constructor function

```
  function ConstructorFunctionCircle(radius) {
      this.radius = radius;
      this.area = () => this.radius * 20;
  }
```

Then I created objects I log the area in a console:

```
  const constructorFunctionCircle = new ConstructorFunctionCircle(20);
  const factoryFunctionCircle = CreateCircle(20);

  console.log(`factoryFunctionCircle ${factoryFunctionCircle.area}`);
  console.log(`constructorFunctionCircle ${constructorFunctionCircle.area}`);
```

The result is:

```
   factoryFunctionCircle  400
   constructorFunctionCircle () => this.radius * 20
```

So, I understand that in case of a constructor function, I should invoke a method using ().

How then can I create a getter property using constructor function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a real constructor *function* you have to use `defineProperty`:

```
  function ConstructorFunctionCircle(radius) {
    this.radius = radius;
    Object.defineProperty(this, "area", {
      get: function() {
        return radius * 20;
      }
    });
 }
```

However I would prefer a class instead:

```
  class Circle {
    constructor(radius) {
       this.radius = radius;
    }
    get area() {
      return 2 * Math.PI * this.radius ** 2;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could define another function (lambda in this case) like so:

```
this.calculateArea = () => this.radius * 20;
```

And then have your original property simply call that function:

```
this.area = this.calculateArea();
```

But a class would definitely be the preferable option.